# SOQL QUERY compile time error

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console, developer

My SOQL query results syntax error can you check and confirm if I made any mistake

```
LIst <AggregateResult> results = [SELECT ZTS_EU_Contact__C con,Max(ZTS_EU_call__r.ZTS_EU_Start_Date_Time__c) date from Attendee__C WHERE ID IN: listAttID AND ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted' OR ZTS_EU_Status__c ='Completed' Group BY ZTS_EU_Contact__C];
```

In WHERE condition part I have newly added this part  - AND ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted' OR ZTS_EU_Status__c ='Completed'

error : Error: Compile Error: Expecting ']' but was: 'OR'

Any inputs that would be great

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Try to add brackets, it should work then `WHERE ID IN: listAttID AND (ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted' OR ZTS_EU_Status__c ='Completed')` or add it as list: `WHERE ID IN: listAttID AND ZTS_EU_Status__c IN ('Submitted', 'Completed')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention the `OR` condition in Single block OR Use `IN` Operator to mention more then one values. then only it's can be work properly in SOQL.

Can you please try as follows,

```
LIst <AggregateResult> results = [SELECT ZTS_EU_Contact__C con,Max(ZTS_EU_call__r.ZTS_EU_Start_Date_Time__c) date from Attendee__C WHERE ID IN: listAttID AND (ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted' OR ZTS_EU_Status__c ='Completed') Group BY ZTS_EU_Contact__C];
```

OR

```
LIst <AggregateResult> results = [SELECT ZTS_EU_Contact__C con,Max(ZTS_EU_call__r.ZTS_EU_Start_Date_Time__c) date 
                                   from Attendee__C 
                                   WHERE ID IN: listAttID AND 
                                         ZTS_EU_Status__c IN ('Submitted','Completed') 
                                   Group BY ZTS_EU_Contact__C];
```

Please let me know if it helps